# Grunt concat failing with "Unable to find local grunt"

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed Grunt like so `npm install -g grunt-cli successfully.

I have also installed the grunt-contrib-concat libary succesfully like so: `npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev`

I have created a `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.1.2"
  }
}
```

and a `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';'
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['src/init.js', 'src/Game.js', 'ui/Ui.js', 'ui/AddBTS.js', 'ui/Toolbar.js'],
      dest: 'built.js'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

};
```

Now when I run `grunt concat` I get the following error:

*Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:*

This is my first time using Grunt and I've been trying to solve this problem for over 2 hours now. Please could someone help me and advise what I've not set up correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that Grunt is not installed locally in your project folder (which is different than grunt-cli). You have it in your package.json so try doing `npm install` or alternately `npm install grunt`.

For more information see the [getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) page:

> Note that installing `grunt-cli` does not install the grunt task runner! The job of the grunt CLI is simple: run the version of grunt which has been installed next to a `Gruntfile`. This allows multiple versions of grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.