# Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt. With Gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs, gruntfile, grunt-cli

(beginner post)(OS : mac)

I just install grunt on my local, and edit my "Gruntfile.js" in my project and when I try this :

```
grunt -v
```

It return :

```
Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
```

I'm well in my project and no problem for install using this :

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I miss something ?

Thk for time.

Comment: have you tried `npm install -g grunt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt concat failing with "Unable to find local grunt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694121/grunt-concat-failing-with-unable-to-find-local-grunt)